# Skip the Activity only if account registeration is done

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my project user have to register and then proceed forward.After the restart of the app the login activity should start skipping the registration activity.But the problem arises when user restarts the app without registering,the login activity appears and not the register activity.So plz help me with this issue Thanks in Advance

```
package com.example.mobilefinder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
                    // run your one time code here
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewAccount.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
                    editor.commit();
                }

                    boolean firstboot = getSharedPreferences("BOOT_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstboot", true);
//
                    if (firstboot){
//                      // 1) Launch the authentication activity
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewAccount.class);
                    startActivity(i);   
//                      // 2) Then save the state
                        getSharedPreferences("BOOT_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE)
                            .edit()
                            .putBoolean("firstboot", false)
                            .commit();
                    }

                else
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), enterpass.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

//              Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewAccount.class);
//              startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

NewAccount.java

```
package com.example.mobilefinder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewAccount extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText ed1, ed2, ed3, ed4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newaccount);
        Button ok;
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_account_btn_ok);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_account_name);
        ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_account_email);
        ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_account_pass);
        ed4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_account_repass);

    }

    public final static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        {
            return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String s2 = ed2.getText().toString();
        String s3 = ed3.getText().toString();
        String s4 = ed4.getText().toString();
        if (ed1.getText().toString().length() == 0
                || ed2.getText().toString().length() == 0
                || ed3.getText().toString().length() == 0
                || ed4.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            if (ed1.getText().toString().length() == 0) {

                ed1.setError("field required");

            } else if (ed2.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                ed2.setError("field required");
            } else if (ed3.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                ed3.setError("field required");
            } else if (ed4.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                ed2.setError("field required");
            }
        } else if (isValidEmail(s2) == false) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Email",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (ed3.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too Short",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (!s3.equals(s4)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Dont Match",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Account Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Would you please clear your requirement,i.e, every time you want Register Activity come or first time or any thing else?

Comment: if the user has registered then only skip the registration activity else show the register activity

Comment: ok, I will give you some code, because I have done this kind of project. I think your problem is in SharedPreference. It' not call perfectly

Comment: A small recommendation - try not to start your application with a registration process if you can help it.  See references to the android design documentation about "content first" and [this video for more info][1].  


  [1]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhzAr9reu_4&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8j2B95zGMb8muZvrIy-wcF&index=6

Comment: Save a boolean in SharedPreferences, after registration make it true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move this code inside `NewAccount.class` so `firstboot` will be set to `false` only when the user has authenticated.

```
               // 2) Then save the state
                        getSharedPreferences("BOOT_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit()
                        .putBoolean("firstboot", false)
                        .commit();
```

I've only rewieved it breefly but I'd put it here:

```
 else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Account Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     // set firstboot to false here
        getSharedPreferences("BOOT_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .edit()
                    .putBoolean("firstboot", false)
                    .commit();  

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

Comment: can u plz explain me in a detail as i m newbie... :)

Comment: Sure, just post your authentication `NewAccount.class` calss here.

Comment: Your code does not look good. Your if-else check is not well configured. 
1. you check if firstTime or not. If so, open NewAccount page.
2. after first step, you check again if the firstboot or not. If so, open the NewAccount page again.
You should change your logic. And +1 for @soulreaver .

Comment: @soulreaver :- Bro ur idea is working but now the problem is that after the registration process,on the 1st restart of the app the data entered with the register activity is displayed and on the 2nd restart the register activity is skipped

Comment: So the 2nd time is what you want to achieve (after user registration)?